# Update button after post request without updating whole screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios, state

I'm new to react native. I'm building an app in which there is a detail screen in that there is a **button with text ( CUT )** and **status is 0**  in Backend. When user click on button a post request is called and **status is set to 1** in backend and **button text will convert to ( Processed )**. but now problem is when user clicks on **button(CUT)** it post on api but it's not updating it in real time it fetch all the data again and rendering the whole screen again and then it convert it to **(processed)**. I dont want to render whole screen again I just want to render that button.

[image]

**Redux action File**

```
export const CutDone = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setCuttingLoading());

  axios
    .post(
      `http://192.168.0.1:3000/api/MobileApp/ProcessCutPiece?planDetailId=${id}`
    )
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data.indexOf("Ok") > -1) {
        Alert.alert(
          "Success",
          `Cutting done of id ${id}`,
          [
            {
              text: "OK"
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "Error!",
          `${res.data}`,
          [
            {
              text: "OK"
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: null
      });
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**detail screen**

```
 onProcessedCutPiece(PlanDetailId) {

    this.props.CutDone(PlanDetailId);
  }

<View style={{ alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                    {newItem.Status === 0 ? (
                      <Button
                        bordered
                        small
                        primary
                        onPress={this.onProcessedCutPiece.bind(
                          this,
                          newItem.PlanDetailId
                        )}
                      >
                        <Text>Cut</Text>
                      </Button>
                    ) : (
                      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.processedText}>
                          <Icon
                            type="Feather"
                            style={styles.processIcon}
                            name="check-circle"
                          />{" "}
                          Processed
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    )}
                  </View>
```

**OnPress I only want to render that button not the whole screen again**

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing `dispatch(setCuttingLoading())` from `CutDone` action and in `onPress` method try setting `newItem.status=1`